# How to change the value of the Submit button text when extending ConfigFormBase

Tags: 8, forms

I need to change the value of the Submit button text when extending ConfigFormBase. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The submit button is defined in the base class and you can change it:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $this->t('Save my configuration');
    ...
```